# The DBMS driver exception was: No more data to read from socket

Tags: sql, oracle, weblogic

If I keep below configuration in data source file then.. I am getting issue to deploy ear on WebLogic

Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "xyz" for task "1" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: **java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket**

```
 <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <initial-capacity>10</initial-capacity>
    <max-capacity>10</max-capacity>`enter code here`
    <min-capacity>1</min-capacity>
    <test-connections-on-reserve>false</test-connections-on-reserve> 
    <test-table-name></test-table-name>
    <statement-cache-size>10</statement-cache-size>
    <statement-cache-type>LRU</statement-cache-type>
  </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
  <jdbc-data-source-params>
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. Please [edit] your post to include a [MRE] (with everything necessary to duplicate the issue) and details of the question you want answering.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating your data source by using the admin console,  you may select or by default select the “Keep Connection After Local Transaction” in translation option.
Kindly uncheck that option and try again. It will resolve your issue.

Keep Connection After Local Transaction option will enables WebLogic Server to keep the physical database connection associated with the logical connection when committing a local transaction instead releasing it and getting another physical connection when needed.[1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcesjdbcdatasourceconfigtransactiontitle.html#:%7E:text=Enables%20WebLogic%20Server%20to%20keep,be%20configured%20on%20the%20database.)

For creating/modify of data source use this reference link [2](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/CreateDataSources.html)

Hope this solves your problem and if it's not solving your problem please update us with relevant information such as error messages.. etc.